# Why isn't my SpriteNode being added to the Scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am making a SpriteNode and trying to add it to the scene. It is not showing up even if I use the `[self addChild: child]`. I just can't see where I went wrong. Here is my View Controller.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Pause the view (and thus the game) when the app is interrupted or backgrounded
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleApplicationWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleApplicationDidBecomeActive:)  name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification  object:nil];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [TitleScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

And here is my Scene.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    SKTexture *YellowLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"YellowLabel.png"];
    SKTexture *BlueLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"BlueLabel.png"];
    SKTexture *GreenLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"GreenLabel.png"];
    SKTexture *RedLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"RedLabel.png"];
    SKTexture *WhiteLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"WhiteLabel.png"];

     NSArray *anim = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:YellowLabelTexture, BlueLabelTexture, GreenLabelTexture, RedLabelTexture, WhiteLabelTexture, nil];

    SKSpriteNode *labelNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"WhiteLabel.png"];
    labelNode.position = CGPointMake(160, 400);

    SKAction *actionAnimate = [SKAction animateWithTextures:anim timePerFrame:.5 resize:YES restore:NO];
    SKAction *actionRepeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:actionAnimate];
    [self runAction:actionRepeat];

    [self addChild:labelNode];

}
```

Can someone figure out what is causing the sprite to NOT be added to the scene. Also, How can I add it to the scene? Thanks!

Comment: There is no `viewWillAppear:` method associated with SKScene. You need to add the above code in the `initWithSize:` or the `didMoveToView:` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @akashg said you can't use `viewWillAppear` method, and also you should use runAction for labelNode:

`[self runAction:actionRepeat];` to `[labelNode runAction:actionRepeat];`

here is how your code should look like:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */


        SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
        skView.showsFPS = YES;
        skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

        SKTexture *YellowLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"YellowLabel.png"];
        SKTexture *BlueLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"BlueLabel.png"];
        SKTexture *GreenLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"GreenLabel.png"];
        SKTexture *RedLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"RedLabel.png"];
        SKTexture *WhiteLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"WhiteLabel.png"];

        NSArray *anim = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:YellowLabelTexture, BlueLabelTexture, GreenLabelTexture, RedLabelTexture, WhiteLabelTexture, nil];

        SKSpriteNode *labelNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"WhiteLabel.png"];
        labelNode.position = CGPointMake(160, 400);

        SKAction *actionAnimate = [SKAction animateWithTextures:anim timePerFrame:.5 resize:YES restore:NO];
        SKAction *actionRepeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:actionAnimate];
        [labelNode runAction:actionRepeat];

        [self addChild:labelNode];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```